# If i use my directive more than once, attribute always takes last assigned value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Below I am using my custom directive `type-ahead-custom`twice one after the other.

first time `type-ahead-custom="maps"`
second time `type-ahead-custom="maps1"`

If i access the attribute `type-ahead-custom` value inside my directive it always returns "maps1" .. How can I fix this?

Here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/hXlNJKboSlA2lAvRqYF1

```
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="myCtrl" >
  <div class="form-group">
    <div>
      <label for="account" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 control-label customize-label ">Typeahead 1</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="inner-addon right-addon">

          <input type="text" ng-model="selectedOptions.planes" uib-typeahead="plane as plane.formatted_address for plane in search($viewValue)" type-ahead-custom="maps" typeahead-loading="loadingdata" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="typeahead-4-8758" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

        <div class="form-group">
    <div>
      <label for="account" class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 control-label customize-label ">Typeahead 2</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="inner-addon right-addon">

          <input type="text" ng-model="selectedOptions.plants" uib-typeahead="plane as plane.formatted_address for plane in search($viewValue)" type-ahead-custom="maps1" typeahead-loading="loadingdata" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="typeahead-4-8758" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

// Code goes here

```
var exampleApp = angular.module('exampleApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

exampleApp.directive('typeAheadCustom', function($http, $q) {
return {
    link: function($scope, $element, $attributes) {


        $scope.search = function(newValue) {

           console.log($attributes.typeAheadCustom);
         var dfr = $q.defer();
         $http.get('//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
             params: {
                 address: newValue,
                 sensor: false
                 }
           }).success(function(data) {

              dfr.resolve(data.results);

          });

          return dfr.promise;
        };
    }
}
});

exampleApp.controller('myCtrl', function($http,$scope) {
  $scope.selectedOptions = {};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are not creating a new scope for your directive, basically they are sharing same scope wherever they are applied.

So when you register first instance of your directive `$scope.search` method gets created in same scope with `$attributes.typeAheadCustom` value `map`.

And on 2nd directive execution it overrides old `$scope.search` method which was created by `1st directive` instance & which has `$attributes.typeAheadCustom` value as `map1`.

So that's why when you call `search` method it will always have latest `$attributes.typeAheadCustom` value.

To solve your issue I'd suggest you create your directive with an isolated scope. Which means directive will have its own new scope. So that where ever you place your directive will not have such kind of issues & directive will act as individual component however time you instantiate it on same page.

Now your directive scope is different than the scope of page where directive has been place, so then you can not access that controller value inside directive at that you need to pass required value using inside isolated `scope: { ... }` binding.

Comment: thanks...if i do isolated scope..will i still be able to fire up search function from uib-typeahead

Comment: @whippits rather better tip would be..move `ui-typeahead` inside the directive template only.. and do pass values from outer world to directive isolated scope using `scope: { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Since instantiations of the directive share the scope with other directives, add functions to scope based on the the directive's attribute value.

```
var exampleApp = angular.module('exampleApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

exampleApp.directive('typeAheadCustom', function($http, $q) {
return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        //create object on scope
        scope[attrs.typeAheadCustom] = {};
        var vm = scope[attrs.typeAheadCustom];
        //put function on object 
        vm.search = function(newValue) {
            var message=attrs.typeAheadCustom +
                        '=' + newValue;
            console.log(message);
            //
            //Do more stuff
        };

    };
});
```

Thus the search functions of the different instantiations have different names.

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="selectedOptions.planes" 
     type-ahead-custom="maps1"
     uib-typeahead="plane as plane.formAddress for plane 
                    in maps1.search($viewValue)"
 >

 <input type="text" ng-model="selectedOptions.planes" 
     type-ahead-custom="maps2"
     uib-typeahead="plane as plane.formAddress for plane 
                    in maps2.search($viewValue)"
 >
```

Comment: any ways you are creating new scope variable, then why not suggesting to do it using isolated scope?